# subprocess.Popen misses last output characters

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have a executable I wrote in C++ that write some json to the standard output.

For example running it in the terminal, i have,

```
PS C:\Users\laerne\Projects\pylol> C:\Users\laerne\Projects\d\master\build\bin\Debug\software.exe --opt-descr
[
    {
        "name": "",
        "options": [
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "run"
    },
    {
        "name": "normal-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "info"
    },
    {
        "name": "world-space-direction"
    },
    {
        "name": "position-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "ambient-occlusion"
    },
    {
        "name": "bent-normal-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "ambient-occlusion-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "curvature-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "position"
    },
    {
        "name": "normal-world-space"
    },
    {
        "name": "texture-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "height-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "thickness-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "curvature"
    },
    {
        "name": "color-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "opacity-mask-from-mesh"
    },
    {
        "name": "uv-map"
    }
]
```

I now want to read that json from python.  For that purpose, I call `subprocess` to generate the json.

```
subprocess.Popen(
  [r"C:\Users\laerne\Projects\d\master\build\bin\Debug\software.exe","--opt-descr"],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE ).stdout.read()
```

However, this returns the empty string !  Trying with a bigger json text, I noticed the few final ~200~400 characters are always removed, and I have no idea why.  Can you help me guess why python stubbornly refuses to read the last few characters ?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to wait for the subprocess to finish. Try:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(  [r"C:\Users\laerne\Projects\d\master\build\bin\Debug\software.exe","--opt-descr"],
  stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p.wait()
print(p.stdout.read())
```

Alternatively you can try to use check_output:

```
print(subprocess.check_output([r"C:\Users\laerne\Projects\d\master\build\bin\Debug\software.exe","--opt-descr"])
```

EDIT: there's also a second side to this - an application, that outputs data. Remember to flush stdout in your C++ application.

Comment: I tried to use `check_output()`, I tried to use `wait()` and doing many examples, I figured out that it didn't matter for that small output, or maybe "read()" does a wait by itself.  So, no, I have the same results with `wait()` or `check_output`.

Comment: Lemme edit an answer, as there's a second side to this.

Comment: I forgot the `std::flush` !  Shame on me !  Thank you !